# Requisição método get

Tags: javascript, api, typescript, get, postman

Gostaria de fazer uma requisição get nessa api `https://api-v2.blaze.com/roulette_games/recent`(api externa, não tenho acesso a ela para habilitar cors), porém, quando faço ela me retorna um erro falando de cors, até ai ok, mas ai eu faço uma requisição pelo insomnia ou postman, e eles me retornam os dados corretos. Ai eu fiquei na duvida, eles não fazem tipo um fetch? Como eles me trazem os dados corretos?

Answer (score -2):

O erro de *cors* ocorre quando uma requisição é feita por uma origem não autorizada (domínio), desta forma ocorrendo apenas em browsers

Para corrigir esse erro é necessário configurar o *cors* do lado do servidor

Caso esteja usando o express para a criação da API, tente instalar o pacote do cors e configurar a instância *express* desta forma

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```